# Using QEMU (with the VMM GUI) to access old windows 7 drive

Tags: qemu

Awhile ago, I said goodbye to windows 7 (rather than upgrade to Microsoft's latest and 'greatest'), and added a new harddrive to my computer. Today, a few upgrades later, and I'm running the Pop_OS! flavor of Linux (an Ubuntu derivative). However, occasionally I find myself needing a windows program that I don't have an equivalent for on Linux (and wine won't run it). Rather than restarting my computer each time I want to get into it, I've heard there's a way to get a VM program like QEMU with VMM GUI to run my disk as a VM.

However, of the guides I've seen are for taking an empty drive and turning it into a repository for multiple VMs, or using it whole for a fresh VM, not turning an existing OS installation into a VM unto itself. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

1) Make a backup of your Win 7 partition to an external drive or the cloud and verify it's accurate.

2) Make *another* backup of your Win 7 partition to *another* external drive or to a different cloud, and verify it's accurate.

3) Run [SYSPREP](https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/preparing-system-sysprep.html) to [tell Windows 7](https://dtonias.com/sysprep-windows-7-installation/) you're going to [change hardware](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation).

4) You will need to make an image file with a command like

dd if=/dev/sda**X** of=/mnt/old-win-7.img

If Windows 7 was on /dev/sda**2**, then the command would be

```
dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/mnt/old-win-7.img
```

Comment: Will be trying this...